# Efficient way to do intersection of unions in ActiveRecord/Arel (Rails 4)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I am trying to construct a pretty complex ActiveRecord query involving the intersection of two unions.  My solution works, but there are lots of redundancies in the generated SQL.  Is there a more efficient way to do it?

In my universe there are People, Cats, Dogs, Books and Albums.  (This is a toy version of the actual model setup, which involves more complicated associations and thus even uglier SQL.)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cats
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :books
  has_many :albums

  ...
end
```

I want to retrieve all people named Jones who own 1) a pet named Wallace and 2) a book or album released in 1996.  I want to be able to construct the query like this:

```
Person.named("Jones").with_pet_named("Wallace").with_book_or_album_released_in(1996)
```

The "named Jones" part is easy:

```
scope :named, ->(name) { where(name: name) }
```

The other two parts of the query are trickier.  The way I'm doing it now, I'm using Arel methods to construct unions (with a pattern borrowed from this talk: http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/#/):

```
class Person
  ...

  def self.with_pet_named(name)
    with_cat_named = joins(:cats).where(cats: {name: name})
    with_dog_named = joins(:dogs).where(dogs: {name: name})
    with_cat_or_dog_named = with_cat_named.union(with_dog_named)
    from(arel_table.create_table_alias(with_cat_or_dog_named, :people))
  end

  def self.with_book_or_album_released_in(year)
    with_book_released_in = joins(:books).where(books: {release_date: year})
    with_album_released_in = joins(:albums).where(albums: {release_date: year})
    with_book_or_album_released_in = with_book_released_in.union(with_album_released_in)
    from(arel_table.create_table_alias(with_book_or_album_released_in, :people))
  end
end
```

The problem arises when I chain these scopes and methods together.  The correct people are retrieved, but the SQL looks less than stellar.

```
Person.named("Jones").with_pet_named("Wallace").with_book_or_album_released_in(1996).
  to_sql
```

returns

```
SELECT "people".* FROM
  ( SELECT "people".* FROM
    ( SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "cats"
        ON "cats"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones' AND "cats"."name" = 'Wallace'
      UNION
      SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "dogs"
        ON "dogs"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones' AND "dogs"."name" = 'Wallace'
    ) "people"
      INNER JOIN "books"
      ON "books"."person_id" = "people"."id"
      WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones' AND "book"."release_date" = 1996
    UNION
    SELECT "people".* FROM
    ( SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "cats"
        ON "cats"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones' AND "cats"."name" = 'Wallace'
      UNION
      SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "dogs"
        ON "dogs"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones' AND "dogs"."name" = 'Wallace'
    ) "people"
      INNER JOIN "albums"
      ON "albums"."person_id" = "people"."id"
      WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones' AND "album"."release_date" = 1996
  ) "people"
  WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones'
```

I think I want something more like this:

```
SELECT "people".* FROM
  ( ( SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "cats"
        ON "cats"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "cats"."name" = 'Wallace'
      UNION
      SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "dogs"
        ON "dogs"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "dogs"."name" = 'Wallace'
    ) INTERSECT
    ( SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "books"
        ON "books"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "book"."release_date" = 1996
      UNION
      SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
        INNER JOIN "albums"
        ON "albums"."person_id" = "people"."id"
        WHERE "album"."release_date" = 1996
    )
  ) "people"
  WHERE "people"."name" = 'Jones'
```

which, while unwieldy, is at least not redundant.  Is there a way to get a neater SQL query using ActiveRecord and Arel methods, and without changing my models or associations?

Answer (score 3):

without having your db schema it's hard to test this, but I think this should get you closer to the SQL you desire.

note: this 'solution' breaks the method chaining available in your code.

```
class Person
  #…
  def self.with_pet_named(name)
    with_cat_named = joins(:cats).where(cats: {name: name})
    with_dog_named = joins(:dogs).where(dogs: {name: name})
    Arel::Nodes::Union.new(with_cat_named.ast, with_dog_named.ast)
  end

  def self.with_book_or_album_released_in(year)
    with_book_released_in = joins(:books).where(books: {release_date: year})
    with_album_released_in = joins(:albums).where(albums: {release_date: year})
    Arel::Nodes::Union.new(with_book_released_in.ast, with_album_released_in.ast)
  end
  #…
end

inter = Arel::Nodes::Intersect.new(
  Person.with_pet_named('Wallace'),
  Person.with_book_or_album_released_in(1996)
)
p = Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(inter, :p)
Person.from(p).where(p[:name].eq('Jones')).to_sql
```